# Slang for hundred thousands

Tags: single-word-requests

We know that instead of saying "I have one thousand (dollars)" we can say "I have one grand". But what's the slang for a "hundred thousand"

Instead of saying "I have one hundred thousand dollars", how can we say "I have ___"??

That's all, thank you

Comment: You can say I have 100G.

Comment: "a hundred grand"

Comment: *Grand*, *K*, *G*, or (in some cases) *M* all represent *one thousand*, so anywhere you use *one grand* you could also use *a hundred grand*, thus *I have a hundred grand in my retirement account,* or *they keep a hundred K in small bills behind the counter*, or *the divorce lawyer alone is costing me a hundred Gs!*

Comment: In technical circles it would be "100 killobucks".

Comment: Also 100 big ones.  A big one = $1,000.

Comment: Also 100 large if you’re a gangster.

Comment: @Jim - 100 small, if you're a politician.

Comment: In British slang, 100,000 pounds sterling is a *plum*. http://www.aldertons.com/money.htm

Answer (score 1):

The most common shorthand for thousands when referring to money is either "grand", "G", or "K". "G" being the abbreviation for grand and "K" being an abbreviation for kilo which is the 1,000 modifier in the metric system.

You could express your statement in several ways:

"I have 100 grand."
"I have 100K" (often spoken as 'I have a hundred k')

"Grand" is more directly related to money references as it wouldn't make sense to say 'There are 60 grand people in the stadium'. Personally, I tend to use "K" over "Grand" in most instances since it is also the most common way to reference thousands from an accounting perspective and also numbers in general ('There are 60k people in the stadium').

As far as I know, "M" would only reference 1,000 if talking in roman numerals. Normally it would be an abbreviation for million.